# Unity + PHP + SSL + Https + hackers

Tags: php, ssl, unity-game-engine, https

I have a Unity WebGL app running in a web browser that communicates with a remote server using plain old Unity WWW and http://.... that calls several different php scripts on server and sending it parameters using POST and getting stuff back.

In the browser i can easily select the debugging console and see all the php scripts and their parameters being calling, this is something i dont want because then a hacker can do the same and see everything and then hack my website.

Instead of me manually writing code to encrypt and decrypt on both sides, can I just buy an SSL certificate and enable SSL on my website, then use https for all communication.

Would doing this encrypt everything for me automatically so that hackers can't just open their browser console and see which php scripts are getting called and the data being sent and received to/from them?

Thanks

Comment: *Users* ("hackers" or otherwise) can see what their browser is sending to and receiving from your server.  This is normal behavior.  If this information allows them to gain complete control over your server then you need to secure your application.  For starters, *how* are users able to "hack your website" just by *using* your website?

Comment: Probably he's passing userids as parameters for each action in his WebGL game rather than relying on a server-side session to inform the game server what user a request came in from. So if a user sees he's doing this they can just call the url that moves a player specifying some other player's id and move the other player however they like.

Comment: Im just trying to find out if SSL would prevent someone from using their browser to see what im sending from the browser and which php scripts im calling, so that I dont have to go through all the hassle of manually coding encryption and creating server-size sessions etc. Does anybody know if SSL will prevent them seeing it?

Comment: @Programmer2: No, SSL won't prevent that.  SSL encrypts the channel between the browser and the server.  The browser *itself* can still see what it's doing.  It has to.  As for "manually coding encryption", that sounds like an attempt to wave a magic wand without understanding the nature of the problem that you want to solve.  That is, it's not going to solve the problem.  But if you can elaborate on the nature of the problem, we may be able to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide this information from users.  Any user, malicious or otherwise, can see from the console every request being sent by the page.  As for SSL, you can only encrypt your own site, not that of third parties, and a connection between an HTTP and HTTPS page is insecure and will trigger errors.  If your application relies on [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), it will eventually be compromised very easily.  Instead, you should follow [Kerckhoffs's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) and design a more secure application.

**TL;DR**: What you're asking is impossible, and SSL won't help at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135452/discussion-on-answer-by-leo-wilson-unity-php-ssl-https-hackers).